# I`ve sent ETH to the wrong address

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, addresses, transfer

I`ve sent ETH from my gate.io to my metamask and I wrong the last number from metamask, is there any chance to get them back ? In the etherscan.io still shows available.

This is good one:         0x8a040BFA35F5519cd59215538B31b4C1814eF564

This is the wrong address 0x8a040BFA35F5519cd59215538B31b4C1814eF565

Please help me with an advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. You can try to somehow contact the address owner and ask him to send you your eth back, but in the Ethereum realm, there is no back button.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but no. seems like you passed that one into address, on which there's high possibility no one owns yet. You can post a comment into address. If someone contacts you. Cheers!